# C++ - Multiple parameter packs for variadic function

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates

I am pretty new to c++ and for my first project am trying to write an ioc container expanding the concept described in [this blog post](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/567981/anplusiocpluscontainerplususingplusvariadicplustem) by adding variadic arguments to the registering functions. So one parameter pack would be used for variadic arguments and the other one to declare the dependencies of the type to register.

After reading a bit I came across stuff similar to what I tried to do in the end. The function looks like this:

```
template <class T,
        template<typename ...TDependencies> typename TUnused, typename... TDependencies,
        typename ...TArgs>
void RegisterSingletonClassFactory(TArgs...args)
{
    std::string typeKey = typeid(T).name();
    creatorMap_[typeKey] = [this, args...](){
        return new T(GetInstance<TDependencies>()..., args...);
    };

    std::shared_ptr<IHolder> iHolder = instanceMap_[typeKey];
    auto * holder = dynamic_cast<Holder<T>*>(iHolder.get());
    if(holder != nullptr)
        holder->instance_ = nullptr;
}
```

And I call it with `iocContainer_.RegisterSingletonClassFactory<boost::asio::io_context, std::tuple<>>(30);`.

This however gives me the error "*error: no matching function for call to*"... with clang telling me "*candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'TUnused'*".

Is there a way to do this? And what exactly does the error mean?

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean `std::tuple` instead of `std::tuple<>`? I suspect there are other problems here, though.

Comment: Oh std::tuple instead of std::tuple<> seems to fix it, thanks :)

Comment: Why is `TDependencies...` repeated twice? Which pack do you mean in `GetInstance<TDependencies>()...`?

Comment: @Evg It's not really repeated. The first `TDependencies` just names the arguments of the template template parameter. It would be useful for things like `template<template<typename T, T> typename> void foo();`, but it is superfluous in this case. It goes out of scope before the "second" one is declared. The whole `template` header could be written `template <typename T, template<typename...> typename TUnused, typename... TDependencies, typename... TArgs>`. The only thing named `TDependencies` in the body of the function is the second one.

Comment: Now I have the same error when calling the method with `iocContainer_.RegisterSingletonClassFactory<listener::ClearTextListener, std::tuple<boost::asio::io_context>>(boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(address, portNr));`
Could it be a similar fix? (I sure hope so)

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't refresh the page and didn't see the comments... but yeah, like @HTNW said

Comment: @HTNW, yeah, that's the reason I asked. The first `TDependencies` pack is misleading and one might think it is somehow related to the second one. Given the previous comment, I guess this is indeed the case.

Comment: `std::tuple` is a template, `std::tuple<boost::asio::io_context>` is a type. They are different entities. For a template template parameter you can't use type parameter `std::tuple<boost::asio::io_context>`. Do you want to extract `TDependencies` from `std::tuple` or do you want to provide them explicitly?

Comment: And what is the role of `TUnused`?

Comment: Well as I wrote in the question I'm new to c++... 
Thought I'd have to name it all
I wanted to extract them from the tuple but right now I'm following the suggestion by @max66 which seems to work really well, I'm at least being bombarded with new errors ^^
The role of TUnused was to provide the compiler with the destinction of the parameter packs... but it seems that was unnecessary in the first place so so much for that :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And what exactly does the error mean?

The error mean that your call

```
iocContainer_.RegisterSingletonClassFactory<boost::asio::io_context, std::tuple<>>(30);
```

doesn't matches the declaration of your template function

```
template <class T,
        template<typename ...TDependencies> typename TUnused, typename... TDependencies,
        typename ...TArgs>
void RegisterSingletonClassFactory(TArgs...args)
```

because your template functions waits for

1. a type parameter (`T`),
2. a template-template parameter (`TUnused`)

and other template parameters when you pass

1. a type paramer (`boost::asio::io_context`)
2. another **type** template parameter (`std::tuple<>`)

If you want to pass `std::tuple` as template-template parameter, you have to pass it without template parameters (`std::tuple`, not `std::tuple<>`).

Given that your `TUnused` parameter is... well, unused,... I suppose that your intention was to use it as type container.

But there is no needs for it.

Not sure but seems to me that your looking for something similar

```
template <typename T, typename... TDependencies, typename ...TArgs>
void foo (TArgs...args)
```

So you can explicit `T` and a (maybe empty) `TDependecies...` list of types.

The `TArgs...` list is deduced from the arguments

The following is a silly, but compiling, C++17 example

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename... TDependencies, typename ...TArgs>
void foo (TArgs...args)
 {
   std::cout << "T:" << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;

   std::cout << "TDependecies list:" << std::endl;

   ((std::cout << "- " << typeid(TDependencies).name() << std::endl), ...);

   std::cout << "TArgs list:" << std::endl;

   ((std::cout << "- " << typeid(TArgs).name() << std::endl), ...);
 }

int main()
 {
   foo<std::string, short, int, long, long long>(0, 1l, 2ll);   
 }
```

where `T` is `std::string` (the first explicit template parameters), `TDependencies...` is `short, int, long, long long` (the following explicit template parameters) and `TArgs...` is `int, long, long long` (deduced from the `0, 1l, 2ll` arguments).

Observe that you don't need the `TUnused` template parameter.

Answer (score 2):

It is clear now that `std::tuple` was not really needed in the original problem, but for completeness let me give an example of how `Dependencies` could be extracted from the `std::tuple`-like types<sup>1</sup>. All we need is an additional level of indirection:

```
template<class T>
struct wrapper {};

template<class T, template<class...> class Unused, 
         class... Dependencies, class... Args>
void RegisterSingletonClassFactoryImpl(
    wrapper<Unused<Dependencies...>>, Args... args) {

    std::string typeKey = typeid(T).name();
    creatorMap_[typeKey] = [this, args...]() {
        return new T(GetInstance<Dependencies>()..., args...);
    }; 
    // ...
}

template<class T, class Unused, class... Args>
void RegisterSingletonClassFactory(Args... args) {
    RegisterSingletonClassFactoryImpl<T>(wrapper<Unused>{}, args...);
}
```

Now

```
RegisterSingletonClassFactory<T, std::tuple<A, B, C>>()
```

will call `RegisterSingletonClassFactoryImpl()` with `Dependencies` pack being `A, B, C`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Any other type list

```
template<class...>
class type_list;
```

can be used instead of `std::tuple`.