# c++ - Multiple parameter packs for variadic struct

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

This question is similar to this [C++ - Multiple parameter packs for variadic function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63179866/c-multiple-parameter-packs-for-variadic-function), but specifically for structs.

The following compiles and runs fine (taken from the linked question).

```cpp
template <typename... TDependencies, typename ...TArgs>
void fooFunction(TArgs...args) {
    std::cout << "TDependecies list:" << std::endl;
   ((std::cout << "- " << typeid(TDependencies).name() << std::endl), ...);

    std::cout << "TArgs list:" << std::endl;
   ((std::cout << "- " << typeid(TArgs).name() << std::endl), ...);
}

int main()
{
    fooFunction<std::string, short, int, long, long long>(0, 1l, 2ll);
}
```

as the type deduction will be successful based on the arguments provided to `fooFunction`.

My question is, why does the deduction not work with a struct like this?

```cpp
template <typename... TDependencies, typename ...TArgs>
struct fooStruct {
    fooStruct(TArgs...args) {
        std::cout << "TDependecies list:" << std::endl;
        ((std::cout << "- " << typeid(TDependencies).name() << std::endl), ...);

        std::cout << "TArgs list:" << std::endl;
        ((std::cout << "- " << typeid(TArgs).name() << std::endl), ...);
    }
};

int main()
{
    fooStruct<std::string, short, int, long, long long> s(0, 1l, 2ll);
}
```

The compiler error is `parameter pack ‘TDependencies’ must be at the end of the template parameter list`.

I've tried adding a user deduction guide like below, but that gives the error `trailing return type ‘<type error>’ of deduction guide is not a specialization of ‘fooStruct<<declaration error>, TArgs>’`

```cpp
template <typename... TDependencies, typename ...TArgs>
fooStruct(const TArgs...) -> fooStruct<TDependencies..., TArgs...>;
```

is there any way to accomplish this?

For context the ultimate goal is to have something like this to zip the two variadic packs together.

```cpp
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct base {

};

template <typename... T1, typename ...T2>
struct child : base<T1, T2>... {

    child(T2... args) {}
};
```

`child` here will use `T2` but base will use `T1` and `T2`.

Comment: The simplest would be to make the constructor a template by removing `TArgs` from class template parameter list as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77965728/12002570).

Answer (score 3):

> is there any way to accomplish this?

Yes, the simplest way is to make the constructor itself a template as shown below:

```
template <typename... TDependencies> //removed TArgs from here
struct fooStruct {
    template<typename ...TArgs> //added this 
    fooStruct(TArgs...args) {
        std::cout << "TDependecies list:" << std::endl;
        ((std::cout << "- " << typeid(TDependencies).name() << std::endl), ...);

        std::cout << "TArgs list:" << std::endl;
        ((std::cout << "- " << typeid(TArgs).name() << std::endl), ...);
    }
};

int main()
{
    fooStruct<std::string, short, int, long, long long> s(0, 1l, 2ll); //works now !!
}
```

Comment: I should have made it more clear in my question but I do want access to `TArgs` outside of the constructor. The last code snippet shows it best that I want to inherit from multiple base classes by folding while zipping these together `struct child : base<T1, T2>...`

Answer (score 2):

The error is clear: the standard forbids it.

To solve your problem you need a factory function.  And you know how to write that factory function.

Partial CTAD is banned by the standard.  It was complex and not clear so they nixed it.  So there is no way to deduce half of the arguments, other than a factory function.

```
template<class...Explicit, class...Implicit>
foo<pack<Explicit...>, pack<Implicit...>>
 make_foo(Implicit...);
```

using

```
template<class...>struct pack{};
```

to delimit arguments into two packs.